# Child item not showing up in expandable recycler view

Tags: android, expandablerecyclerview

> This is my adapter class

```
public class GenreAdapter extends ExpandableRecyclerViewAdapter<GenreViewHolder, ArtistViewHolder> {
    Context context ;
    LayoutInflater inflater ;

    public GenreAdapter(List<? extends ExpandableGroup> groups,Context context) {
        super(groups);
        this.context = context ;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public GenreViewHolder onCreateGroupViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_genre, parent, false);
        return new GenreViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public ArtistViewHolder onCreateChildViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_artist, parent, false);
        return new ArtistViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindChildViewHolder(ArtistViewHolder holder, int flatPosition, ExpandableGroup group,
                                      int childIndex) {
        final Artist artist =(Artist) group.getItems().get(childIndex);
        holder.setArtistName(artist.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindGroupViewHolder(GenreViewHolder holder, int flatPosition,
                                      ExpandableGroup group) {
        holder.setGenreTitle(group);
    }
}
```

> This is my model class

```
package com.nmn.expandablerecycler.utils;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

import com.thoughtbot.expandablerecyclerview.models.ExpandableGroup;

import java.util.List;


public class Artist  implements Parcelable {

    private String name;
    private boolean isFavorite;


    public Artist(String name, boolean isFavorite) {
        this.name = name;
        this.isFavorite = isFavorite;
    }

    protected Artist(Parcel in) {
        name = in.readString();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
  /*  public String getTitle()
    {
        return title ;
    }*/
    public boolean isFavorite() {
        return isFavorite;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Artist)) return false;

        Artist artist = (Artist) o;

        if (isFavorite() != artist.isFavorite()) return false;
        return getName() != null ? getName().equals(artist.getName()) : artist.getName() == null;

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = getName() != null ? getName().hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (isFavorite() ? 1 : 0);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(name);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public static final Creator<Artist> CREATOR = new Creator<Artist>() {
        @Override
        public Artist createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Artist(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Artist[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Artist[size];
        }
    };
}


public class Genre extends ExpandableGroup<Artist> {

    public Genre(String title, List<Artist> items) {
        super(title, items);
    }
}

>This are my viewholder classes 
public class ArtistViewHolder extends ChildViewHolder {

    private TextView artistName;

    public ArtistViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        artistName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.artist_name);
    }

    public void onBind(Artist artist) {
       artistName.setText(artist.getName());
    }

    public void setArtistName (String name )
    {

    }
}


public class GenreViewHolder  extends GroupViewHolder {

        private TextView genreTitle;

        public GenreViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            genreTitle =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.genre_title);
        }

        public void setGenreTitle(ExpandableGroup group) {
           genreTitle.setText(group.getTitle());
        }
}

>this is the main activity 

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ArrayList<Artist>artists = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0 ; i<6 ;i++)
        {
            artists.add(new Artist("naman",true));
        }

        ArrayList<Genre> genres = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0 ; i<6 ;i++)
        {
            genres.add(new Genre("Sufi",artists));
        }


        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        //instantiate your adapter with the list of genres
        GenreAdapter adapter = new GenreAdapter(genres,this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

> The text on the artist(child) name is not shown up . Althiugh the parent (genre text ) expands and collapses as well .Let me know how to
>   show the text of child (artist) item in this expandable recyclerview

Comment: Did you debug and check if `onBindChildViewHolder` is being called or not

Comment: yes it is called ...checked via printing log .

Answer (score 0):

Dude this might sound silly, but your `setArtistName` method is empty. paste this code `artistName.setText(artist.getName());`

Comment: While posting to SO, please make sure you have self verified the code enough. Irrespective of that silly mistakes are silly and creep up.

Answer (score 0):

The library documentation has error

```
public void onBind(Artist artist) {
   artistName.setText(artist.getName());
}

public void setArtistName (String name )
{

}
```

In this snippet just change the name of method from onBind to setArtistName and remove the empty method you created.

Answer (score 0):

I was also implementing com.thoughtbot.expandablerecyclerview. What I did in the same scenario was, in the custom class that is extending ExpandableGroup, I override getItems() and getItemCount() methods and provided the values which I wanted as "child"-expanded state.